# Incorrect information in file

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

```
[ERROR] mysqld: Incorrect information in file: '/mysql/#sql50f_eb5128_1.frm'
```

Received this error while restoring old snapshot. How to confirm which table which is causing this error message? I'm sure this must be MySQLdatabase as all other databases are INNODB. I am using mariadb 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

after some research and consult with other DBA friends concluded that it is a temporary table as any temporary table is named in this pattern only.